# css font-size based on div width

Tags: javascript, css, width, containers, font-size

I'm looking for an adaptive `font-size` solution to apply such a `font-size` that will fit snug into available `width` of the `container`.

Tried `vw` units in `css`, and `fittype.js` but my content users need to be able to provide string with text of any length.

Can this be somehow achieved with `css` only, or `canvas/svg` - I'm looking form a performance optimized solution. My last resort will be dynamically checking `font-size` and `width` of the `container` with `js`, but I'm afraid these will slow down page load with too many iterations.

Please suggest how this can be best dealt with? Thanks

Comment: read the question @al-Zami

Comment: Tried vw units in css and fittype.js, but none works for me - I'm thinking if there's a way to embed text as an object and set its width to 100% filling the container - just like I do it with images and other media

Comment: You cannot do this with CSS alone; `vw` relates to *viewport* width, not to container element's width. Doing it in JavaScript is rather straightforward, and you seem to know to do it.  Especially without any specifics, how could anyone say what is “best”. If the container width is set in a systematic and controlled manner, you might be able to base the font size on the underlying logic.

Comment: Ok. So that's what I pressumed. My container is elastic, width in % units, I guess I'll get back to my initial idea and calculate the width dynamically with js. I've already checked SVG for embedding text and it also doesn't help much.